# How to avoid data label in excel line chart overlap with other line/label?

Tags: excel, label, linechart, overlap

[image]

**My data:**
I have 2 series of values plotted on the same line chart in Excel (see above). I want to show the data label for both lines on the chart. However, it seems like the data labels will overlap with either the green dot/red dot/line. If I adjust the position of the data labels, it will only work for this 2 series of values. Sometime the values will change and cause the purple line to be above the black line, and then the data labels overlap with something else again.

**My question:**
May I know if there is any way to prevent this overlapping issue?
Any helps will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick here to solve the problem:

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/1062385-data-labels-positions-automatically-update-on-chart-to-avoid-overlap.html